# How can I get the newly entered text from a textarea?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, textarea

I want to make a chat program like Google Wave that shows what is typed in real-time. For the moment I'm just using a textarea. I just want to know what change the user made to the textarea (either one character or pasted text) without having to perform a diff on the whole textarea. I was something along the lines of using a `setTimeout` with the `oninput` event but I believe this could only give me the "before text" and the "after text". Any ideas?

Comment: You might want to take some time checking out meteor.js http://meteor.com It is a javascript framework for writing realtime apps – like chat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this type of functionality is most likely accomplished using a message batching type setup.

here's how it would break down:

1. attach event handlers to a text area to track modifications on the character level (think, keydown, keypress, keyup, etc..) and log these into a message buffer
2. you'll want to have a backup for "end transaction" type events like "onchange", "onpaste", etc.. that serve to check the integrity of you're state and be prepared to run a "full re-sync" (eg. signal other clients to do a full "pull") if you think you have a mismatch
3. on an interval (every 0.3 - 1 second), you empty the message buffer and re-transmit the messages to other clients (direct connect [websockets?], or indirect via server)
4. when a client receives messages, they process them in the same order they've received them [hopefully] ending up with the same state, error or conflict fallback: signal full sync
5. on a full sync client should re-pull the full state and attempt to place the focus/carrot as close to the last position as possible

on a side note: this is greatly simplified with a concept of "regions" where you can do clean full swaps on your region without affecting mine...

hope this helps -ck

Answer (score 1):

You will want to look at the `key` events: `keydown`, `keypressed`, `keyup`

[W3C keyboard events](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#events-keyboardevents)

But you also need to consider pasted text – which might not have a key press.

One strategy, to simplify event handeling, would be to have a 'submit' button.  Then you will know when the user is done with their statement.

Answer (score 1):

Track the value of your text area with setInterval and compare it against itself to see if it changes. This works for pastes, normal key presses, etc.

**Example:**

```
var lastVal = $("#myTextInput").val();
setInverval(function(){
    if($("#myTextInput").val() != lastVal) {
        lastVal = $("#myTextInput").val();
        // the text changed, do something with the current value (AJAX, whatever)
    }
}, 300);
```